# VSCode + ROS 2 error squiggles stop working

Tags: ros2, vscode

I am using VSCode for ROS 2 development, and generally this works really well but every so often suddenly the error squiggles stop working, with following error message:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (<some cpp file in workspace>).
cannot open source file <some hpp file in workspace> (dependency of <some other hpp file in workspace>)
```

This is my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/ros2_rolling/install/**",
                "/opt/gazebo_harmonic/install/include/gz/**",
                "/opt/bridge/install/**",
                "/usr/include/eigen3/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I also tried with `"${workspaceFolder}/install/**"` instead of `"${workspaceFolder}/**"` but that didn't resolve it.

If you google, there are a ton of suggestions, but none seem to resolve the issue.

Anyone here ran into the same issue and could resolve it?

In the past I had this issue because I had added multiple folders to a workspace and each had their `.vscode` folder, but in this case it's a single-workspace setup. :-(